# Kafka Streaming 1.0 Assign partition to thread

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streaming, with a stateless simple processor topology.

I have a topic with 100 partitions, have 2 machines with 50 threads each, and running the same streaming app, so that eventually I will have a 1-1 mapping between.

Messages in the topic are already keyed messages.

I have a logical constraint, that once a thread hooked to a partition or more, it should continue processing those partitions (of course until a restart happens, it will reshuffle)

I saw from logs that the thread is repeatedly (Re-)joining the consumer group.

My question, Do kafka-streaming api guarantee the thread to process the same partition(s) it was originally hooked on the app startup, or it do reshuffelling every now and then.

I checked the documentations, but I was not able to find anything discussing this in details.

Here is the code I am using:

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KStream<String, Document> topicStreams = builder.stream(sourceTopic);

topicStreams.process(() -> new CustomMsgProcessor());

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);
streams.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question, Do kafka-streaming api guarantee the thread to process the same partition(s) it was originally hooked on the app startup, or it do reshuffelling every now and then.

When your Streams application starts, [it builds the number of threads](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.java#L652-L673) you specified and sets the threads to listen for partition assignment. When partitions are assigned to a thread, it [creates tasks for those partitions](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/TaskManager.java#L137). When those partitions receive input, the thread [processes the input with their respective tasks](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamThread.java#L918).

So if I understand your contraint correctly, [given the lifecycle of the Streams application](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.java#L158-L183), yes: once a thread receives a partition assignment, it will continue processing that partition until it shuts down or rebalances.

---

In [Architecture](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html) it says:

> Kafka Streams creates a fixed number of stream tasks based on the input stream partitions for the application, with each task being assigned a list of partitions from the input streams (i.e., Kafka topics). The assignment of stream partitions to stream tasks never changes

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I am asking as I saw this behavior in one of my applications, which is kafka logs keep saying it is rebalancing and the threads are rejoining partitions, which I became sure from logs that partition get processed by multiple threads, I saw a pattern, as a certain point where connecting to db I saw the rebalance, do the thread has a sort of timeout limit that needs to be configured?

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t understand

Comment: What I got from your answer, is that once the thread hooked to partition (or set of partitions), it will continue receiving msgs from those partitions till the application get closed or a new threads joins the group, Am I correct?

Comment: Great!, what I was saying, is that I saw an opposite behavior, I see that in the same application run that threads get shuffled every few seconds, and partitions are re-assigned, any ideas why this could be happening in the same run?

Comment: Oh that's very strange. If you log `Thread.getCurrentThread().getName()` from a processor, it should return the same thread until it is reassigned.